# Is there a way to disable an asp.net dropdown list from the vb code behind?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Is there a way to disable an asp.net dropdown list from the vb code behind?

```
<select id="reassign_reason" name="reassign_reason">
```

This is the name of my drop down list and I tried this in the code behind in vb.net

```
reassign_reason.disabled = True
```

Thanks

Comment: Your select is not an `asp.net` dropdown - it is an HTML one. Do you want it to be a serverside one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the control to be a server side control if you want to be able to control it from your code behind.

To do so, add a `runat="server"` attribute to the element.

```
<select id="reassign_reason" name="reassign_reason" runat="server">
```

Then in your code behind:

```
reassign_reason.Disabled = True
```

Comment: @Daren, since Oded answered your question, you should accept it as the answer by click the check mark to the left of his answer.